# Send values over wifi via Matlab

Tags: matlab, wifi, communication

I need to send int and double values from one computer to another. The two pc's are connected to the same wireless network and the values I get are generated by a Matlab code. Can this be done in Matlab or do I need to use a medium between the two?

Comment: If you can do it in Java you can do it in Matlab.  Alas my Java is too rudimentary to provide any more 'help' than this.  But there is a ton of material on using Java in the Matlab command window.  Let Google be your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Sending data over WiFi is basically the same as sending it over any network. You'll need the other computer's local IP address (various ways to find this on different operating systems, [ask google](https://www.google.com/search?&q=find+a+computer%27s+local+IP)). You don't want to use an external IP address like [this](http://www.whatismyip.com), since this would usually require you to change some settings on your router (e.g. port forwarding).

Once you have a local IP address, you could use something like Sockets - Loren has a good [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/05/27/transferring-data-between-two-computers-using-matlab/).